# Cron-type scheduling for an ASP.NET web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, cron, scheduler

I was wondering if a web application for ASP.NET supports a scheduling feature similar to Cron jobs on a Unix-like platform?

PS. I'm coding in VS2010 using C#, and I need this feature to run C# script on a configurable schedule, based on date & time.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a windows service project type. 
You coluld use a web project as an editor, to configure various parameters, and persist them to a db or file, and then read them from the windows service.

Using a web app to execute some task at different intervals is not the best ideea.

While this could be done in theory, maybe you can split it in 2projecs: 1 web app that saves config params and maybe diplays the task status, and 1 windows service that reads the params, executes the tasks and maybe updates its status.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if I'll be able to install a Windows service on that server though...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the Windows Task scheduler to schedule the C# script?  Do you not have admin privileges?

I use cron to kickoff my scheduled jobs on unix servers, and the Windows Task Scheduler to run them on Windows servers.

Comment: I need this to be configurable from a web app, so that a user there could schedule the task. Is that available via a C# script?

Answer (score 0):

We have a commercial product that may be exactly what you're looking for. JAMS is an enterprise grade task scheduler and it includes ASP.NET controls that you can drop onto your web pages. We have controls to schedule, monitor and manage tasks as well as querying past history.

And, our .NET class library can be called from C# (or any other .NET language)

If you're interested, more information is available at:

http://www.JAMSScheduler.com